# Smarty {html_options} in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, smarty, html-select

I am trying to put generated Smarty options list in a JavaScript string but it breaks because of the new lines generated by Smarty. Seems like I cannot filter the html_option after its generation.

Any ideas or solutions, anyone? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Smarty template
    var option_list = '{html_options options=$options_list selected=' + selected_option + '|regex_replace:"/[\r\n]/":""}';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Result:
    var option_list = '<option ....></option>   //SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
<option ....></option>
<option ....></option>';
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Don't use JavaScript - wrap in a select tag in the document OR 2. use the backtick ` instead of quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backtick (`) seems to be changed by TypeScript compilers but fortunately I have finally found some workaround:

```
<script>
var options = '{html_options|strip ...}';
</script>
```

But we also need to set the selected item afterwards:

```
$('#select_id').val(selected_option);
```